# CAS Multifactor Authentication Provider Selection

Tags: cas, google-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am working with **cas-overlay-template** project in version **6.1.4**. I have implemented two mfa providers on my CAS, **Google Authenticator** and **CAS Simple**. Both are working, I have tested them separately and I have got the results I've expected.

Until now, I have been activating the mfa modifying the cas.properties file adding this properties: `cas.authn.mfa.globalProviderId=mfa-gauth` when I wanted to use Google, or `cas.authn.mfa.globalProviderId=mfa-simple` when I used the CAS itself.

Well, in CAS documentation is mentioned that is possible to enable a provider selection menu, if resolved more than one just by adding this propertie: `cas.authn.mfa.provider-selection-enabled=true`. So, my configuration is the following:

```
cas.authn.mfa.provider-selection-enabled=true
cas.authn.mfa.globalProviderId=mfa-gauth
cas.authn.mfa.globalProviderId=mfa-simple
```

But when I try to login with any user (I'm using the default one casuser:Mellon), CAS don't show me a menu in which I can select the following mfa provider, It directly goes to mfa-simple provider.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that your are not using the correct configuration properties. What you are describing is not multi-factor authentication, is delegated authentication. Please check [this ](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html#register-providers).

Comment: Yes I'm talking about mfa, https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/mfa/Configuring-Multifactor-Authentication.html. I know what delegation is, I have already implemented it with Google and Facebook. What I'm talking about is to select the second authentication factor after I enter my user:pass in the login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, in CAS documentation is mentioned that is possible to enable a provider selection menu, if resolved more than one just by adding this properties:

So far so good.

> So, my configuration is the following:

That's the problem. You are not resolving/triggering more than just one provider. You start with `mfa-gauth` and then override it with `mfa-simple`. In CAS 6.1.x, the `globalProviderId` only accepts a single identifier. It's not a list or a container of any kind to accept more than one value. This has been addressed in the next coming release.

At the moment, to resolve more than one provider you will need to assign the MFA providers to a registered service definition. Like so:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "^(https|imaps)://.*",
  "name": "Example",
  "id": 1,
  "description": "This service definition defines a service.",
  "evaluationOrder": 1,
  "multifactorPolicy" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceMultifactorPolicy",
    "multifactorAuthenticationProviders" : [ "java.util.LinkedHashSet", [ "mfa-duo", "mfa-gauth" ] ]
  }
}
```

This means, provider selection can be enabled on a per-application basis. Alternatively, you can write a small groovy script to return more than one provider back to CAS, allowing the selection menu to display the menu items.

Read [this post](https://fawnoos.com/2019/05/13/cas61x-mfa-selection-strategies/) for full details.